# Finding closest range to given number

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following data

```
id   range_min   range_max
1    1           10
2    4           7
3    5           10
4    5           5
```

I would expect:

```
input   id
6       2
5       4
3       1
```

Any idea how to do this in MSSQL?

Comment: Why would 5 return 4 and not 1 or 3?

Comment: because it is an exact match. I'm looking for the tightest range. something like range being 70% of score and average in range scoring 30%

Comment: What is a score?  What does "average in range scoring 30%" mean?

Comment: i was referring to the median. so median of id #2 is 5.5. that account for 30% of the match. and tightest range would account for 70% of the match

Comment: @Dave.Gugg it will return row with id #4 which has 5 as min and max as 5 as is tightest range to input number

Comment: Can you please explain logic of expected output? Please edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT TOP 1 numbers.input, data.range_min AS id
FROM (
  SELECT numbers.input, data.range_min, data.range_max - data.range_min AS span
  FROM numbers, data  
  WHERE numbers.input >= data.range_min AND numbers.input <= data.range_max
)
ORDER BY span
```

You don't specify where `input` comes from. I assume that it comes from a table: `numbers`.

When `input` belongs to different ranges, I have chosen the tightest one (hence sorting on `span` which is max - min).

Comment: what if i would also want to order by how centered it is within range, so that results would be id's of: 4,2,1,3

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to set up your expected results:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      range_min INT ,
      range_max INT
    )
INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( range_min, range_max )
VALUES  ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 4, 7 ),
        ( 5, 10 ),
        ( 5, 5 )

DECLARE @input INT = 6;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        range_min ,
                        range_max ,
                        RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY range_max - range_min ) AS tightness
               FROM     #temp
               WHERE    @input >= range_min
                        AND @input <= range_max
             )
    SELECT  id
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   cte.tightness = 1
```

Change the @Input variable to see the different results.  This uses only the "tightness" of the range to find the best match.  If you need something aside from that you should lay it out clearly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @id int 

Select  top 1 *
From TableName
Where Rmin<=@id and RMax>=@id
Order by (@id-Rmin) + (RMax-@id)
```

Comment: (@id-Rmin) + (RMax-@id) = Rmax - Rmin: see my answer

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
select count(id) as id from table where input>=range_min and input<=tange_max
```

Comment: This does not return the expected result set.

Comment: Did you try that statement to see if it brings the OP's expected results?  It doesn't.  When I put in 6 I get ID = 3, the OP is expecting id = 2.